# Windows phone 8 emulator debugging error: "a specified communication resource (port) is already in use by another application"

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Error:

> A specified communication resource (port) is already in use by another application

I'm debug application and it kept the same error. I tried everything:

- Deloy project -> Fail
- Reset phone -> Fail
- Deleting the %user%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Phone Tools\CoreCon -> Fail

It is worse.

Comment: Did you rebuild your project?

Comment: When I've had this error before it has been because the emulator is already debugging another application. Do you have any other applications currently debugging on the emulator?

Answer (score 2):

I've had this issue before, restarting Visual Studio fixed the problem. Also, make sure your Visual Studio is updated to the latest version.

Comment: I confirm. While it is issue with one of services (possible to fix "manually"), it is by far easier and faster to just restart VS.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting you VS should help. Also make sure that you are not running multiple projects at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Its because another application may be running in the same simulator. First stop the running Application and try again will solve the issue.

Comment: doesn't help. restarting doesn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled for long with this - eventually found that my SQL db in my project's properties was wrong. The Build Action cannot be set to Embedded Resource. If I change it to Resource, the error goes away.